# Will OS upgrade from Snow Leopard to Mavericks erase other partitions?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade, partition

I have Macbook6,1 Late 2009 Unibody white Snow Leopard with dual boot Debian Wheezy installed on the other partition. 
I use EFI to show boot options at startup.

Will upgrading to Mavericks overwrite/delete other partitions?

Debian is what I use primarily. I would however like to upgrade to Mavericks for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses! From your responses I feel hopeful about this ...I will let you know how this goes

Comment: You can't directly upgrade from Snow Leopard (10.6.x) to Mavericks. You need to take a mid step of either Lion or Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Updating will not affect any partitions you do not choose in the set-up process. If you're not asked, then it will install on the partition the OS X install originated on.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there should not be a problem, if!

As always before doing the OS upgrade it is recommended to do a back up- just in case.

There are, however, a couple situations in which you might consider a [clean install.](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056563/should-you-do-a-clean-install-of-mavericks.html)

The first is if you’ve done some funky partitioning of your Mac’s startup drive that prevents the Mavericks installer from creating the special Recovery HD partition.

<sub>The installer creates an invisible, bootable, 650MB partition—a portion of a drive the operating system treats as a separate volume.</sub>

Mavericks will also "updates" the EFI partition.

To see all your current set up (including hidden partitions) use the

`diskutil list` in Terminal